# Suddeny can't paint texture, object looks greyed out

Tags: texture-painting

I'm trying to paint a texture and all of a sudden the object in the viewport turned greyish or washed out and I can't paint on it at all. Meanwhile I can still paint in the flat 2D texture view no problem. Is there some mask turned on or something? Why [image]does it look like this?

Comment: hello could you please share your file?

Comment: I solved it. "Paint Mask" button on top suddenly was enabled. Not sure if I hit some hotkey that does it accidentally, but I never actually clicked it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out. That tiny button "Paint mask" (2 squares on top next to "texture paint" drop down) was enabled. I DID NOT press it for sure and didn't click it. Absolutely not sure why it suddenly was enabled, but that was the culprit.